# Why parameters become zero in Group Lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression

I've already studied about Ridge, Lasso and Group Lasso. Lasso can estimate essential parameters. That is, some parameters got zero.

By the way, in group lasso, why parameters corresponding to a Group got zero? Moreover, group lasso uses L2 norm.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fairly helpful primer for [studying group LASSO](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/sparse-grlasso.pdf), particularly sparse group LASSO.

In general, your $L_2$ penalty term aims to shrink the coefficients of unimportant factors to zero, if possible.  More on that [can be found here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4479976/#S3title).

It is difficult to answer your question, as it is pretty vague.  You say you have already studied LASSO, so you must understand why it can produce 0-valued coeffocients, as a quasi-feature-selection method.

Comment: I've read it. But I couldn't understand, so I made a question. Lasso uses L1, but Group Lassouses L2. How does it work?